# How do you scan a text file and convert it to a 2D char array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, n-queens, charat

I have been given text files and I am trying to convert them into a 2D char array for further use. What is happening is it appears to be taking the first indices and copying that over and over until it has reached the int size and it believes there is only one column. I wondered also if it has something to do with charAt as I am not familiar with it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        System.out.println("Enter file path here!");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File(input.nextLine());
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        int size = inputFile.nextInt();
        char[][] testBoard = new char[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            String line = inputFile.next();
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                testBoard[i][j]= line.charAt(i);
                System.out.println(testBoard[i][j]);
            }
        }
```

An example of a file given is

```
4
BQBB
BBBQ
QBBB
BBQB
```

Please help its messing up my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `testBoard[i][j]= line.charAt(i);` try `testBoard[i][j]= line.charAt(j);`

Comment: This may have solved the problem, I'm working through it right now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two loops. Write your loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String line = inputFile.nextLine();
    testBoard[i] = line.toCharArray();
}
```

Note that a 2-D array in Java is an array of arrays. Thus `testBoard[0]` should be assigned `{'B', 'Q', 'B', 'B'}`, `testBoard[1]` should be assigned `{'B', 'B', 'B', 'Q'}` and so on. This is what this loop is doing.

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Okay.. but testBoard has been defined as a 2D array, will it still be?

Comment: @cb-9099 - Yes...that is what I've explained. Where is the doubt?

Comment: Well I had a 2D array declared for testBoard and it just didn't like it very well when I tried to compile it. It's okay now though I believe the problem has been solved! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @cb-9099 - This code compiles and works perfectly. It seems you are not able to visualize a 2-D array. I recommend you go through some tutorial to understand Java 2-D array. If you want me to explain, I can help you with a diagram which will help you understand the concept.